# Why is my colour font not being outlined in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, icon, font-design, outline

I am working on a card game and I'm using template `.svg` files in **Inkscape** to create cards quickly. My end goal is to be able to place **coloured icons inline with text** without having to lay them out by hand, and I'm trying to make a colour font to use in Inkscape for this purpose.

I've used **High-Logic's Font Creator** to make a `.ttf` SVG font with colour embedded, but for readability the icons need an outline, and for whatever reason **Inkscape is not outlining the symbols in the font I made**. However it *is* outlining the unused letters in the font as normal.

[image: Text on a grey background. The top text is white with a black outline. The bottom text is a mix of coloured icons with no outline, and white letters with a black outline.]

I could recolour each symbol in the text individually in Inkscape, but at that point I might as well lay them all out by hand.

I suppose my questions are:

- Why is Inkscape not outlining the symbols in my font?
- Is there an easier way to get an outline than drawing outlines for my 22 icons by hand within the font itself?
- Is there a better or easier way to make colour-embedded fonts than the 30-day trial of Font Creator?

Additionally, **Krita** is able to outline my font, but it *ignores the embedded colour*.

I presume it's to do with how Inkscape generates or detects outlines but I have no idea how to fix it or give Inkscape the necessary information.
I can provide the `.ttf` or the Font Creator file if it would help.

Many thanks

Comment: Inskcape doesn't fully support colour fonts, at least not the display of them. I suspect this is the main issue.  However if you use colour fonts, and output the SVG, they should display in browser.  I don't know if this will work if you try to use some kind of outline though.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here . .  If the icons were not colour, you could instead apply fills to glyphs individually within the same text object: [see example](https://imgur.com/zThZGg8), then apply a stroke to serve as the outline.  I don't know how helpful this would be for your particular use-case.

Comment: Here's [another example](https://imgur.com/YKH8LFo) made using a mono emoji font (Segoe UI Emoji) to check that it works.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ah ok, didn't know to what extent Inkscape supported colour fonts, thanks. You might be right, filling them individually may be the best option if the outline issue can't be solved, it would just be nice not to have to, y'know? Alternatively I suppose I could export the text sans outline then add it in after, but that would just be another step to repeat hundreds of times.